# RecyclerView trouble

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I just changed my application from grid view to `RecyclerView`.

My `RecyclerView` contains some Items. When you on one Item an other activity should open with the more Information about the Item.

Now when I click on the upper Items this works as it should. But when I scroll down a little bit, and click on a list item, there the app goes back to the first activity of my whole application but I do not get an exception.

This is very odd since the `on click` for every item in my `RecyclerView` triggers the very same method.

When I debug it everything works fine until I do the `startActivity(intent)` method. Then the debugger simply says no frame available.

So I am not so long in android developing so I do not really know what the mistake could be.?

EDIT:
I put two extras in the intent one is my own class and one an array of my own class. Everytime I just put extra in the intent(doesn´t matter witch one) it works fine(exept of the missing information of course)

Comment: try to clean your project and run again

Comment: @KaranMer didn´t work...

Answer (score 0):

Add this code at your onClick method

```
    if (recyclerView.getScrollState() != RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are having problem with your Intent. Well here is how you do it..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),DetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("TAG","VALUE");
startActivity(intent);
```

you don't need to put your current activity's context anywhere else, just put all the details of your selected item that you need to show in your detail activity, in extras with unique tag and then extract them in your destination activity.

Comment: if this doesn't help thn you are having problems in your onClick method you implemented to get the event on your recyclerview item...